# How to convert SQL Server image type to normal text in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

In our Database, doc and pdf files content has been stored as **image** datatype in SQL server.
But now  I want to convert to original format .doc and .pdf files.
Can anyone please help me how to do this in c#.
Thanks

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: `IMAGE` (which should be replaced with `VARBINARY(MAX)`) is a **binary** data type - you cannot easily convert it to *normal text* - it's not *normal text* - it's a document format. You'll have to store it to disk and open it with the appropriate application

Comment: On what marc_s said, I'll add that you are requesting two different things: `How to convert SQL Server image type to normal text in c#?` and `now I want to convert to original format .doc and .pdf files`

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional variable (field/column) in your database which stores the original filename *with* extension. Then you can simply copy all the bytes form the database (variable/cell/field) to a new file and name it accordingly.

This will *restore* the original file with a matching file extension.

Converting such a file to text is quite another story.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your explanation. I've already additional variable  which stores original file name.

Comment: Probably this helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48619/Reading-and-Writing-BLOB-Data-to-Microsoft-SQL-or or google further...